# stop all video players when starting an other to play?

Tags: video-player, jwplayer

I have a wordpress-page where many videos are posted. Some are embedded Vimeo or YouTube Videos, some are hosted on the server and played with wordpress-JW-Player Plugin.

The thing is, on some pages there are up to 10 videos and in "worst" case, three different players. When the user watches a video, and then starts a second one, the first video should stop automatically.

My question is: is there a Wordpress-compatible-JavaScript/WP-Plugin/etc. which provides such a behavior, when the user starts a second video the first one shell stop (and if he starts a third, then the second one shell also stop, and so on).
Or do I have to configure the WP-Plugin of JQ Player in an other way?

**UPDATE**

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/coreyworrell/1313678) script, but it seems no to do anything in my case ... (I don't get any errors - it seems just to do nothing)

Comment: I think it is not related to WordPress?

Comment: Asking to recommend a product (plugin, theme, book, hosting provider), tool, library or off-site resource is out of scope of the site (see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ), as it attracts opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ok, thanks for that advice. now gimme the advice, where I could post that kind of question. ;)